# How can I see the current state and next state signal?

Tags: vhdl, counter, vivado

I was looking at this code:
http://vhdlguru.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/how-to-implement-state-machines-in-vhdl.html

and I wanted to know how you would run the simulation in vivado, but then apart from clock and output, also see the current and next state signals.

I have tried to put signal Current_s and Next_s in test bench, but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks for help.

Edit

Been asked to include code so it seems to be like this would be the line I want that would put the signals that I need into the code: 
    signal current_s,next_s: state_type;

Comment: Please include a minimal verifiable example of code directly in the question, otherwise when that blog disappears some time from now the question won't make any sense to future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Select your DUT (Device Unter Test) in the Scope window. You should be able to see the signals in the "Objects"-window. Right click on a signal and select "Add to wave window".
Start or rerun the simulation.

Comment: I don't get anything for current and next state. I've tried to put state_type is (s0,s1,s2,s3); 
signal current_s,next_s: state_type; in the test bench but my state is always S1.

Comment: When I do not edit the test bench at all I get the seemingly correct values for the states, but the actual numbers do not show in the signal boxes.

Comment: Ahaha sorry my bad I saw some weird symbols and had to zoom in, thanks!